# LibGDX: Particle scale

Tags: java, android, libgdx, particles

In my game I use

```
static final float FRUSTUM_WIDTH = 10;
 static final float FRUSTUM_HEIGHT = 15;
```

So when I draw the particles they take the whole screen and are huge! So how do I scale them down to fit my needs?

//Pew Labs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you use the particle editor (to be honest I don't think it's a good idea for sizing the particles, as you mentioned the particles won't get too small (for anything else I really recommend it)) or you just open the particle effect file. It should be generated by the editor or you can copy it from the examples. In this file search the fields below:

```
- Scale - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.6
highMax: 0.6
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
```

Adjust the `highMin` and `highMax` as needed.

Comment: This and all the others not working with the latest library, any help?

Comment: Personally, I haven't used libgdx in a while, sorry :(.

Answer (score 25):

```
ParticleEffect pe = new ParticleEffect();
    pe.load(Gdx.files.internal("data/particle/particle.p"), Gdx.files.internal("data/particle"));
    pe.setPosition(x, y);

    float pScale = 0.2f;

    float scaling = pe.getEmitters().get(0).getScale().getHighMax();
    pe.getEmitters().get(0).getScale().setHigh(scaling * pScale);

    scaling = pe.getEmitters().get(0).getScale().getLowMax();
    pe.getEmitters().get(0).getScale().setLow(scaling * pScale);

    scaling = pe.getEmitters().get(0).getVelocity().getHighMax();
    pe.getEmitters().get(0).getVelocity().setHigh(scaling * pScale);

    scaling = pe.getEmitters().get(0).getVelocity().getLowMax();
    pe.getEmitters().get(0).getVelocity().setLow(scaling * pScale);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use the particle editor and adjust the size there:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1255

Answer (score 2):

I have used the same approach as Victor but what worked for me:

```
    ParticleEffect effect = new ParticleEffect();
    effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("particle/version1.p"), Gdx.files.internal("particle"));
    effect.setPosition(x, .y);
    float pScale = 0.02f;
    float scaling;
    Array<ParticleEmitter> emitters = effect.getEmitters();
    for (ParticleEmitter e : emitters) {

        scaling = e.getScale().getHighMax();
        e.getScale().setHigh(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getScale().getLowMax();
        e.getScale().setLow(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getVelocity().getHighMax();
        e.getVelocity().setHigh(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getVelocity().getLowMax();
        e.getVelocity().setLow(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getSpawnHeight().getHighMax();
        e.getSpawnHeight().setHighMax(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getSpawnHeight().getLowMax();
        e.getSpawnHeight().setLowMax(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getSpawnHeight().getHighMin();
        e.getSpawnHeight().setHighMin(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getSpawnHeight().getLowMin();
        e.getSpawnHeight().setLowMin(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getSpawnWidth().getHighMax();
        e.getSpawnWidth().setHighMax(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getSpawnWidth().getLowMax();
        e.getSpawnWidth().setLowMax(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getSpawnWidth().getHighMin();
        e.getSpawnWidth().setHighMin(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getSpawnWidth().getLowMin();
        e.getSpawnWidth().setLowMin(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getXOffsetValue().getLowMax();
        e.getXOffsetValue().setLowMax(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getXOffsetValue().getLowMin();
        e.getXOffsetValue().setLowMin(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getYOffsetValue().getLowMax();
        e.getYOffsetValue().setLowMax(scaling * pScale);

        scaling = e.getYOffsetValue().getLowMin();
        e.getYOffsetValue().setLowMin(scaling * pScale);
    }
    effect.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, to handle my particle size depending on the user's screen, I use `ScalingViewport` which allows you to work at a fixed size and it'll automatically scale depending on the device'd screen size. I usually put the `ScalingViewport` for a `Scaling.fill` in its constructor; that prevents the particle from stretching and looking bad.