# how to scale or resize particles programmatically in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using particle effect in libgdx and everything is working fine , but I want to scale/resize the particles for various screen sizes. How can i do this in program itself and not in .p file?

Comment: Well i got the ans here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11078584/3318971

Comment: possible duplicate of [LibGDX: Particle scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708490/libgdx-particle-scale)